# Getting answers as per the perception of others only, not at all mine?

Tags: personal-practice

I am not good in english, but i am getting answers somehow. If i say about people who have had answered. They have suggested everything as per their own perception. Is that good to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a "Dhamma"-rule of thumb, if answers lead you you further away from Samsara and towards Nibbana, i.e. by reducing *greed, hatred and delusion*, then those answers, can be considered wholesome.

Answer (score 2):

Of course they are good to you if it changes you for the better. If nothing can be changed, like a solid rock, then it does nothing good.

But everything is impermanent, even a rock can change, so there will be changes which should be good.